# AucTeX multiple files parsing not working

Tags: auctex

I have not been using LaTeX for quite some while, so I might be missing something obvious. I have a multiple file document and want to make `AUCTeX` aware of the master file. The minimal example looks like this: A master file `test.tex` and one `section` in `test-1.tex` in the same directory.

*test.tex*

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
\lipsum[1]

\include{test-1}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

*test-1.tex*

```
\section{Second}
\lipsum[2]

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "test"
%%% End:
```

If I compile `test.tex`via `C-c C-c` everything works fine but if I am in `test-1.tex` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
l.1 \section
            {Second}
--- HELP ---
TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled the
name. If this message occurs when a LaTeX command is being processed,
the command is probably in the wrong place---for example, the error
can be produced by an \item command that's not inside a list-making
environment. The error can also be caused by a missing \documentclass
command.
```

Also *Switch to master file* `C-c ^` does not work, so there is something not working with the multiple file parsing. I have tried `C-u C-c C-n` to reset `AUCTeX` without any effect. What am I missing?

Comment: What's the value of the variable `TeX-parse-self`?  Have you tried to hit `C-c C-n` in `test-1.tex` **and** in `test.tex`?  Your example works without a problem for me -- I have set `TeX-parse-self` to `t`.

Comment: `TeX-parse-self` is set to `t` in my config and I tried `C-c C-n`in both documents without any change. It is still not working.

Comment: Sorry, hard to tell.  I suggest you start debugging.  The usual way is to update AUCTeX to the latest version from ELPA, start Emacs with the `-Q` switch, eval `(package-initialize)` and open your .tex file.  This works for me as well.

Comment: I will see when I have the time for real debugging and will post my results here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the encouraging comments I was able to work it out. I added `turn-on-outline-minor-mode` to `LaTeX-mode-hook` for historical reasons and it breaks the multiple files parsing. I have no idea what is happening under the hood but can easily live without it.

With this config everything works fine:

```
(use-package tex
  :ensure auctex
  :config
  (setq TeX-auto-save t
        TeX-parse-self t
        TeX-save-query nil)
  (setq-default TeX-master nil)
  :hook
  (LaTeX-mode . flyspell-mode)
  (LaTeX-mode . flyspell-buffer)
  (LaTeX-mode . tex-fold-mode)
  (LaTeX-mode . turn-on-reftex))
```

Comment: I don't `use-package`, but the following `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'outline-minor-mode)` works for me and doesn't break AUCTeX.

Comment: Weird! I am traveling right now and can’t check. But even with a vanilla config using `-Q` this line caused trouble.